# How is derived the relation between capacitances when a $Y-\Delta$ transformation is applied in a capacitors network?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, capacitance

A [$Y-\Delta$ transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) can be applied to circuits in order to make an equivalent circuit (but simpler to put in terms of series/parallel devices). Wikipedia and other books show how to deduce the relation between resistances in a network. You can use [this tool](http://spruce.flint.umich.edu/~jalarie/jaa_un.htm) (as pointed by @Alfred_Centauri) to calculate the relation between capacitances in a capacitors network. But, How exactly is derived that relation from basic principles?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81129/2451 (now deleted so 10k only)

Comment: Hi Phyllipe. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Hint:  capacitance combines like conductance, the reciprocal of resistance.

Comment: Hint: Let one node hang to derive one $Y-\Delta$ relation. Now repeat with the two other nodes to derive two more $Y-\Delta$ relations.